# How to increment a day in a date that is stored in a variable

Tags: bash, osx, date

I am on OSX and have a date variable stored in `$d` which is formatted like `%Y_%m_%d`. So `echo $d` would give something like `2016_03_29`. I want to increment the day by 1 so it becomes `2016_03_30`. From what I've read on this, I tried doing

```
date +"%Y_%m_%d" -d "${d:0}${d:4:0} + 1 day"
```

and

```
date -j -f '%Y_%m_%d' -v '+1d' "$d" +'%Y_%m_%d'
```

but neither worked.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in your input from YYYY_MM_DD. You can do:

```
d=2016_03_29
date +%Y_%m_%d -d  "$(echo $d | sed 's/_/-/g')+1 days"
```

to get

```
2016_03_30
```